# Apple Watch recording audio interface crashing after starting to record

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos-2

I'm trying to record audio with the Apple Watch, using the `presentAudioRecorderControllerWithOutputURL` method.

I'm using Xcode 7.0 beta 5, iOS9 beta, WatchOS 2 beta & Swift2.

It runs great on the emulator. However, once on the actual device, it crashes when the method is called.

Here is my current code :

```
@IBAction func onClickSpeech() {
    let filePaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
        NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,
        NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask,
        true)
    let documentDir = filePaths.first!
    let recSoundURL = documentDir + "/record.m4a"
    let nsUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(recSoundURL)

    let audioOptions = [
        WKAudioRecorderControllerOptionsActionTitleKey  : "Recording title",
        WKAudioRecorderControllerOptionsAlwaysShowActionTitleKey : false,
        WKAudioRecorderControllerOptionsAutorecordKey: true,
        WKAudioRecorderControllerOptionsMaximumDurationKey: NSTimeInterval.infinity
    ]

    presentAudioRecorderControllerWithOutputURL(
        nsUrl,
        preset: WKAudioRecorderPreset.NarrowBandSpeech,
        options: audioOptions as [NSObject : AnyObject]) { (didSave, error) -> Void in
            print("didSave:\(didSave), error:\(error)")
    }
}
```

`recSoundURL` is a valid path.

The error I'm getting in device logs :

```
Aug 18 16:42:12 Sennetts-AppleWatch mediaserverd[283] <Error>: 16:42:12.532 EXCEPTION: [0x1f1ac000] >va> 565: kAudioHardwareUnknownPropertyError: "AudioObjectHasProperty([goin/glob/0]) returned false."
Aug 18 16:42:12 Sennetts-AppleWatch mediaserverd[283] <Error>: 16:42:12.555 ERROR:    [0x1f1ac000] >va> 240: CAException caught by ExceptionBarrier: 2003332927.
```

Any idea would be greatly appreciated as I can't figure this one out. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it is a problem or a bug from Apple. As we can see in the logs, AudioObjectHasProperty([goin/glob/0]) returned false. They may fix this after the public release of watchOS 2. You should file the bug to Apple using bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Yep, I've already done it. I was hoping to maybe find some luck here. Now we'll just to wait.

Comment: I wonder if it is because you need to write the audio file to someplace else.  In the sample code Apple provided they wrote it to NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("some identifier") [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/samplecode/WatchKitAudioRecorder/Listings/WatchKitAudioRecorder_WatchKit_Extension_AAPLAudioRecordingInterfaceController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016225-WatchKitAudioRecorder_WatchKit_Extension_AAPLAudioRecordingInterfaceController_m-DontLinkElementID_12)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the code below (Using [app group's](http://techotopia.com/index.php/Sharing_watchOS_2_Media_Files_Using_App_Groups) shared folder)

```
    @IBAction func recordAudio() {

    let fileName = "audioFile.wav"

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let container = fileManager.containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier(Constants.kAppGroupId)
    self.saveUrl = container?.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)


    let duration = NSTimeInterval(120)
    let recordOptions = [WKAudioRecorderControllerOptionsMaximumDurationKey : duration]
    presentAudioRecorderControllerWithOutputURL(self.saveUrl!,
        preset: .WideBandSpeech,
        options: recordOptions,
        completion: { saved, error in

            if let err = error {
                print(err.description)
            }
            if saved {
                // Write code to execute when audio file gets saved.

            }
    })
}
```